# directing based on GET request parameters in django

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm in c.html (http://localhost:8000/practice/c) and I click a link that changes my url to

http://localhost:8000/practice/c/?q=1

this is urls.py

```
url(r'^$', prac_c),
url(r'^q=\d',fetch_c),
```

and this is views.py

```
def prac_c(request):
    return render_to_response('subject/c.html', {"problem_list":problem_list})
def fetch_c(request):
        qno = request.GET.get('q')
        if qno:
            return render_to_response('subject/que.html', {'qno':qno}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but I'm not getting directed to que.html. Something wrong with the urls.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### What the URLconf searches against
>
> The URLconf searches against the requested URL, as a normal Python string. This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain name.

[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against)